# Select the direct next of a certain element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a class to the next p element after the item that is clicked.
In my function the part that removes the class is working but the selector for the p element is not correct so nothing is happening with that.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gsd3226w/)

```
function classChange() {
    if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        //do nothing
    }
    else {
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).next('p').addClass('active');
    }
}

$('h1').click(function() {
    classChange();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

In your `classChange()` function, `this` refers to the Window object (assuming the function is in the global scope).

If you want it to refer to the clicked `H1` element, define the click event like this:

```
$('h1').click(classChange);
```

If you want to toggle the next `P` element's display, define `classChange()` like this:

```
function classChange() {
  $(this).next('p').toggleClass('active');
}
```

[**Fiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/2of0eraa/)

If, instead, you want to always show one of the `P` elements, define it like this:

```
function classChange() {
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).next('p').addClass('active');
}
```

[**Fiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/2of0eraa/1/)

Comment: thanks all great answers, I'm accepting Rick's as it answers my question in the simplest way.

Answer (score 1):

The `this` in classChange is not what you think it is.
You can try do the below to bind the `e.target` as `this` in the `classChange()` function:

```
function classChange() {
    if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        //do nothing
    }
    else {
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).next('p').addClass('active');
    }
}

$('h1').click(function(e) {
    classChange.bind(e.target)();
});
```

Or you can pass in the `e.target` like this `classChange(e.target)` and you use it like this:

```
function classChange(target){
    if($(target).hasClass('active')){
    } else { 
          $('.active').removeClass('active');
         $(target).next('p').addClass('active');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing something wrong here..

One noticeable is

```
if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
```

$(this) returns window and not the selected element in which the event is binded to the h1.

Since you are invoking a function to do that, you can add a parameter to that function passing the $(this).

Here is the demo..

```js
function classChange(e) {
  //$(this)
    //would return window and not the h1
    if($(e).next('p').hasClass('active')) {
        //do nothing
    }
    else {
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(e).next('p').addClass('active');
    }
}

$('h1').click(function() {
 classChange($(this));
});
```

```css
p {
  opacity: 0;
}

.active {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>
Hello
</h1>
<p class="active">
  hello
</p>
<h1>
Goodbye
</h1>
<p>
  Goodbye
</p>
```